# What is the reason behind defining react component the way?

Tags: reactjs

I am curious why React does not define the components like the following instead. It has to be invoked the component and its returned value for the first time and to re-render the only thing that needs to be done is invoke the returned value which is a function as well. The functions that do not need props would be defined in the outer function scope and the ones that do would be defined in the inner function scope.

```js
function Component(){
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  //other states
 
  const incerement = () =>{
    setState((oldState) => oldState + 1)
  }

  // define other functions that do not need props but does state here
 
  
  return (props) => {

    //define the functions that need props here

    return (
      <div>{count}</div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: useState would not be executed on rerender.

Comment: Why it is needed to be executed `useState` on re-render?

Comment: It returns current value of the state, not only sets it on first render. Without it, how would rerender know the value?

Comment: What if you need props to manage state?

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković do whatever you want in the inner function scope.

Comment: But what would be the advantage of your way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

The most obvious drawback here is the lack of subsequent calls to **useState**. Calling it not only sets the default value on first call but also retrieves current value on each next call.

In your current proposal, the inner scope is supposed to somehow obtain current value of the state but there seems to be no way of how it would be possible.

Anyway, it doesn't seem clear what your proposal would improve. It's still a function React calls. However, the drawback of your approach is obvious: on the first call, React would have to call the upper level function and the inner function afterwards and then call only inner function on subsequent calls. This would mean React would have to handle the first call differently than subsequent calls.

What React does currently, however, is it calls components in the very same way, regardless of the distinction between the first and all other calls.

Comment: I thought it would avoid to be created the functions that no need props and setState functions that hooks return on each calls.

Comment: @Muzaffer: that was a good question of yours. You possibly missed the fact that useState has to be called upon each render but often clever optimizations can be introduced by refactoring existing code. Also, others could possibly learn something from the question and the discussion.

Comment: By the way I do not agree this  "What React does currently, however, is it calls components in the very same way, regardless of the distinction between the first and all other calls."  If it is like that then the state would be initial value on every calls. Because we pass the initial value to the useState, which in this case is 0.

Comment: @Muzaffer: not exactly. React stores the state externally, outside of the component and it knows if it's the first call (that sets the initial value) or the subsequent call (that just return the value). It's the beauty of this call that it looks same in both cases.